# Why are there no USB-c to USB-c ethernet cables?

Tags: ethernet, usb-c

I have a USB-C ethernet adapter. I have an ethernet cable. I have another USB-C adapter. I connect the ethernet cable to both adapters and now I can connect two laptops using USB-C. It works just fine, but it's rather clunky, so I would rather just have a single USB cable with type C in both ends. Whereever I look on the web, I can't find a single one. I can find dozens of adapters.

Does anyone have an explanation for this, or even better, an actual cable I can buy? :)

EDIT: It seems my question is difficult to understand. What I am asking, is; if I am easily able to connect an ethernet cable to two USB-C ethernet dongles, why can't someone make me an ethernet cable with two USB-C dongles built-in? Is ad-hoc wired connections that uncommon these days?

Comment: Those USB-C to ethernet adapters are actually doing a lot of the work here, a USB cable on its own wouldn't even look like a network to either PC. USB is also not designed to let two computers talk to each other. One end of the cable has to behave like a client and most computers are hard-wired to assume they are the host, so when you connect their USB ports together they will not be able to agree on which is the host and which is the client. Thunderbolt uses a USB-C port but it is a totally different signal that does come with the circuitry needed to have two thunderbolts talk to each other.

Answer (score 2):

As all new devices must have USB-C, this cable is going to be the single most popular cable type in future.

Make sure it is also good for Thunderbolt [at least Thunderbolt 3], though both USB 4 & Thunderbolt 4 are already rolling out - still using the same cable type, but in higher spec.
One of the main issues with USB-C is it's really hard to tell just by looking what spec they have. Some are only any use for charging, some for data & some will carry video too.

Here's the first of many pages full, in different spec…
https://www.startech.com/en-us/search?search_term=usb-c%20cable

[image]

To carry Ethernet, the devices at each end must have that capability [USB 3.0 & above].
[See also Share internet from a computer to a another computer via a normal USB](https://superuser.com/q/1711536/347380)

Comment: I think your answer needs to be edited to very clearly state that this will only work with both PCs using Thunderbolt. Thunderbolt allows for actual host to host networking but USB protocol does not, one of the devices must have a special chipset that appears as a USB client. Most PCs do not have this special kind of USB implementation. (Most phones do though!)

Comment: Actually no, there's not a single phone in existence which would have a Thunderbolt controller in it. Also StarTech is vastly overpriced.